# Regular Expression with ASCII 96

Tags: javascript, java, regex, ascii

I'm looking for a regular expression that allows only Alphanumeric characters but not special characters such as ASCII 96 for instance.

Right now I'm using this one:

**/[^\dA-z0-9]/g**

This regex allows Alphanumeric characters but also ASCII 96 (a.k.a `).

Could anyone help me?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `[A-z]` also matches `[`, ``\``, `]`, `^`, and `_`. So, you might need `/^[0-9a-z]*$/i`

Comment: `A-z` does not do what you think it does. Use `A-Za-z`

Comment: As john16384 said I've changed my expression with A-Za-z and It works!. Thanks so much ;)